# inf2cat 22.9.10 error

Tags: inf

I'm trying to sign old Hitachi driver that makes USB flash drive appear as fixed disk
(Quite useful when you have fast, large thumb drives)

Driver itself works fine but I constantly get same error when try to get it signed:

Errors:

```
22.9.10: cfadisk.sys in [cfadisk_copyfiles] is missing from [SourceDisksFiles] section in
\cfadisk.inf; driver may not sign correctly until this is resolved.

22.9.10: disk.sys in [gendisk_copyfiles] is missing from [SourceDisksFiles] section in 
cfadisk.inf; driver may not sign correctly until this is resolved.
```

This is my .inf file:

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=DiskDrive
ClassGuid={4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Provider=%HGST%
DriverVer=10/14/2012,9.9.9.9
CatalogFile=cfadisk.cat

[Manufacturer]
%HGST% = cfadisk_device,ntAMD64

[DestinationDirs]
cfadisk_copyfiles=12    ; %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers
gendisk_copyfiles=12    ; %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers

[cfadisk_copyfiles]
cfadisk.sys

[gendisk_copyfiles]
disk.sys

[cfadisk_device]
%Microdrive_devdesc% = cfadisk_install,USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_Extreme&Rev_0001

[cfadisk_device.NTamd64]
%Microdrive_devdesc% = cfadisk_install,USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_Extreme&Rev_0001

[cfadisk_addreg]
HKR,,"LowerFilters",0x00010008,"cfadisk"

[cfadisk_install]
CopyFiles=cfadisk_copyfiles,gendisk_copyfiles

[cfadisk_install.HW]
AddReg=cfadisk_addreg

[cfadisk_install.Services]
AddService=disk,2,gendisk_ServiceInstallSection
AddService=cfadisk,,cfadisk_ServiceInstallSection

[gendisk_ServiceInstallSection]
DisplayName    = "Disk Driver"
ServiceType    = 1
StartType      = 0
ErrorControl   = 1
ServiceBinary  = %12%\disk.sys
LoadOrderGroup = SCSI Class

[cfadisk_ServiceInstallSection]
DisplayName    = "CompactFlash Filter Driver"
ServiceType    = 1
StartType      = 3
ErrorControl   = 1
ServiceBinary  = %12%\cfadisk.sys
LoadOrderGroup = Pnp Filter

; -----------------------

[Strings]
HGST = "Hitachi"
Microdrive_devdesc = "SanDisk Extreme"
```

I was using this tutorial as reference point:
http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Blog/tabid/62/EntryId/63/Sign-your-unsigned-drivers-Damn-It.aspx

cfadisk.inf and sys can be downloaded here:
link is at the beginning of first post

http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1655684

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

I just used chkinf utility on this .inf file
Here is the output:

```
C:\DriversCert\SanDisk\cfadisk.inf: FAILED
NTLOG REPORT--------------
Total Lines:         62  |
Total Errors:         1  |
Total Warnings:       4  |
--------------------------
Line 0: ERROR: (E22.1.1003) Section [SourceDisksNames] not defined. 
Line 0: WARNING: (W22.1.2212) No Copyright information found. 
Line 0: WARNING: (W22.1.2111) [SourceDisksFiles] section not defined - full CopyFiles checking not done.
Line 17: WARNING: (W22.1.2112) File "cfadisk.sys" is not listed in the [SourceDisksFiles].
Line 20: WARNING: (W22.1.2112) File "disk.sys" is not listed in the [SourceDisksFiles].
```

I'm really no programer so I really don't understand what does all this mean.

Strange thing is that driver does work, I just can't get i signed.

Thank you!

Best regards,

Walter

Comment: Managed to find another version of the same driver which doesn't make problems with inf2cat.
If anyone is interested in using this driver, you can find it here:
http://forums.mydigitallife.info/archive/index.php/t-29248.html?s=b1eaf8f6e01ce3049673242ef83cdb4e
I still have a problem signing that driver but I'll open another thread for that.
Thank you!
Best regards,
Walter

Answer (score 2):

It means that some sections are missed. In your case they are `[SourceDisksFiles]` and `[SourceDisksNames]`
In this specific situation you just should add:

`[SourceDisksFiles]`
`cfadisk.sys = 1`
`disk.sys = 1`

`[SourceDisksNames]`
`1 = %DiskName%, ,`

and also add a record to `[String]` section in the bottom:

`DiskName="Disk Drive"`